# confused `printenv` with `declare`

Tags: linux, mac, unix, environment-variables, freebsd

I am using macOS. I am confused `printenv` with `declare`.

I run these 2 commands right after a restart without any other proceeding settings.

`printenv` outputs

```
PWD=/Users/soplus
```

This is reasonable since this is my username to login system.

`declare -xp` outputs

```
declare -x PWD="/private/var/folders/78/ngsn15lj24s72n8hjnj4zkxr0000gn"
```

I guess this is set by vscode, I ran "vscode interactive python" before.

What is the difference between this two settings for the same environment variable?

Where are the config files to store them respectively?

Comment: `PWD` is the path of your current working directory. It isn't set in a config file, it's a dynamic setting that changes every time you use `cd` to move to a different directory.

Answer (score 1):

`printenv` is an external command. It prints exactly what is in the "environment variables"

`declare` is a shell built-in. It shows what shell variables are set to. These may or may not be exported as environment variables for child processes.

PWD is not a regular environment variable. It is set by the shell each time a `cd` command is executed. It can be set "manually" to something unrelated but will be reset by the next `cd` command.